# Top header bar with position fixed on iOS chrome moves about when you scroll

Tags: html, ios, css, google-chrome

The following simple page with a position fixed header bar, works fine in most browsers etc. But on iOS in google chrome if you scroll up and down the page eratically eventually the header bar moves down the page a bit, like the following screen shot.

Any ideas how to fix?

[Test page](http://chapmantrippgraduates.cre8.onl/positiontest.html)

Thanks :)

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>position test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: fixed; background-color: aqua; width: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; line-height: 60px; height: 60px;">
        Fixed header
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 60px;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta aliquet dictum. Aliquam massa libero, consectetur et purus sed, luctus porttitor ligula. Phasellus tempus risus at elit sagittis, sed tincidunt erat rutrum. Donec non dictum turpis. Vestibulum sapien tellus, tincidunt sed ex a, pretium facilisis est. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce laoreet turpis turpis, a rhoncus diam fringilla ac. Proin turpis arcu, hendrerit viverra neque quis, placerat tempor ligula. Duis ut scelerisque ante. Etiam posuere est ut molestie fermentum. Sed feugiat tortor at libero ultrices, vitae consectetur nibh luctus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Sed nulla enim, tincidunt non laoreet quis, congue aliquam nisl. Sed dapibus in erat cursus rutrum. Nullam efficitur sem ipsum, vitae sagittis est tristique vitae. Ut dignissim est eget nisi condimentum posuere. Duis nec neque tempor, finibus sem sed, varius risus. Nullam convallis imperdiet sem vel sagittis. Nulla ultricies sagittis vestibulum. In semper ante ipsum, ac dignissim diam bibendum et. Nam in sapien sem.
        </p>
        <p>
            Phasellus neque nibh, pharetra ac dui et, iaculis lacinia ipsum. Phasellus laoreet eros ut lectus viverra dictum. Mauris vitae neque maximus, hendrerit enim gravida, ornare magna. Sed rhoncus vitae nunc sed iaculis. Donec vitae enim ut enim fermentum scelerisque. Nulla ut vestibulum leo. In ut urna in neque tempor maximus non et massa. In eu tincidunt quam. Donec eu lectus vehicula, consequat enim et, porttitor libero. Phasellus magna tellus, rhoncus non quam vitae, congue sagittis nunc. Mauris bibendum ultrices arcu a lobortis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut quis mi sit amet nulla tincidunt tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nam at interdum nulla, eget ultricies libero. Suspendisse est elit, malesuada sit amet hendrerit nec, posuere et purus. Vivamus sed eros ut nisi cursus hendrerit. Curabitur vel lacus maximus, tempus nulla sed, volutpat risus. Etiam in blandit quam. Nullam lacinia neque eu ligula lobortis facilisis. Quisque ipsum erat, iaculis vitae nunc vitae, egestas feugiat enim.
        </p>
        <p>
            Fusce consectetur leo in est sodales, ut congue est commodo. Donec cursus odio sapien, id malesuada sem dictum eget. Sed sit amet sodales nisl, sed venenatis tortor. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas maximus tortor sed nisi mattis luctus. Proin id diam sagittis ante pulvinar dictum. Donec volutpat nec nibh eget dictum. Donec tellus turpis, hendrerit et risus sed, viverra porttitor leo. Pellentesque non vulputate arcu, eget finibus tortor.
        </p>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas porta aliquet dictum. Aliquam massa libero, consectetur et purus sed, luctus porttitor ligula. Phasellus tempus risus at elit sagittis, sed tincidunt erat rutrum. Donec non dictum turpis. Vestibulum sapien tellus, tincidunt sed ex a, pretium facilisis est. Suspendisse potenti. Fusce laoreet turpis turpis, a rhoncus diam fringilla ac. Proin turpis arcu, hendrerit viverra neque quis, placerat tempor ligula. Duis ut scelerisque ante. Etiam posuere est ut molestie fermentum. Sed feugiat tortor at libero ultrices, vitae consectetur nibh luctus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Sed nulla enim, tincidunt non laoreet quis, congue aliquam nisl. Sed dapibus in erat cursus rutrum. Nullam efficitur sem ipsum, vitae sagittis est tristique vitae. Ut dignissim est eget nisi condimentum posuere. Duis nec neque tempor, finibus sem sed, varius risus. Nullam convallis imperdiet sem vel sagittis. Nulla ultricies sagittis vestibulum. In semper ante ipsum, ac dignissim diam bibendum et. Nam in sapien sem.
        </p>
        <p>
            Phasellus neque nibh, pharetra ac dui et, iaculis lacinia ipsum. Phasellus laoreet eros ut lectus viverra dictum. Mauris vitae neque maximus, hendrerit enim gravida, ornare magna. Sed rhoncus vitae nunc sed iaculis. Donec vitae enim ut enim fermentum scelerisque. Nulla ut vestibulum leo. In ut urna in neque tempor maximus non et massa. In eu tincidunt quam. Donec eu lectus vehicula, consequat enim et, porttitor libero. Phasellus magna tellus, rhoncus non quam vitae, congue sagittis nunc. Mauris bibendum ultrices arcu a lobortis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut quis mi sit amet nulla tincidunt tincidunt.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nam at interdum nulla, eget ultricies libero. Suspendisse est elit, malesuada sit amet hendrerit nec, posuere et purus. Vivamus sed eros ut nisi cursus hendrerit. Curabitur vel lacus maximus, tempus nulla sed, volutpat risus. Etiam in blandit quam. Nullam lacinia neque eu ligula lobortis facilisis. Quisque ipsum erat, iaculis vitae nunc vitae, egestas feugiat enim.
        </p>
        <p>
            Fusce consectetur leo in est sodales, ut congue est commodo. Donec cursus odio sapien, id malesuada sem dictum eget. Sed sit amet sodales nisl, sed venenatis tortor. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas maximus tortor sed nisi mattis luctus. Proin id diam sagittis ante pulvinar dictum. Donec volutpat nec nibh eget dictum. Donec tellus turpis, hendrerit et risus sed, viverra porttitor leo. Pellentesque non vulputate arcu, eget finibus tortor.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be a (recent) known bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585460

Comment: This is a know bug.
bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585460

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try using !important?

```
<div style="position:fixed !important; top:0px !important; left:0px !important;">
```